# Leaving super-capacitor connected to power supply

Tags: charging, supercapacitor, backup

I want to use a 1F-5.5V super-capacitor as a power backup for a 3.3V circuit. As I searched the internet I have to use a circuit for charging the super-capacitor to stop charging when the voltage reaches a specific value. I want to know what happens if I leave the 5.5V super-capacitor connected to the 3.3V power supply via a 1N5822 diode and a 74ohm current-limiting resistor for a long time without the charging circuit?
Note that the circuit is always powered by an external power supply and the super-capacitor is used only for a short time that main power goes out.

Comment: Only downside would be parasitic leakage of the supercapacitor. If a power supply is available, this is probably mW’s you can live with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you be able to calculate this if it was a *normal* capacitor? It's the same! Current will flow from the power supply through the diode+resistor into the capacitor, which will cause the voltage across the capacitor to increase, which will decrease the current flow; it will reach equilibrium and stop charging around around 3.0V to 3.3V (because of the diode's voltage drop).

However, will it work as a backup? Beware that as current is drawn out of the capacitor its voltage will decrease linearly. For example if the capacitor charges to 3.3V and your circuit stops working at 2.64V, you're only using 20% of the "stored current" in the capacitor. And you only charged up the capacitor to 60% of its design voltage to begin with. You're leaving quite a lot of energy on the table there.

You didn't say much about the circuit but if that's okay for you, then it's okay for you. It's perfectly fine to oversize the capacitor since it's easier than converting voltages all over the place. If that's not okay for you, then you might consider using a boost converter to charge the capacitor up to slightly under 5.5V, and a linear, buck or buck-boost converter to produce a consistent 3.3V from that.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if having a supercap as the energy element is a good idea. If you calculate the energy density of a supercap, it is less than that of a battery. Supercaps offer a good combination of energy density and power density but their power density is less than that of the electrolytic capacitors and their energy density is less than that of batteries. A supercap + battery combination gives you good energy and power density!

Comment: I think, the circuit in question here tries to avoid all the additional requirements, that come up using a battery.